# How can I set button below image?

Tags: html, css, image, button

I have one little problem:

[image: http://prntscr.com/61tzt2]

How can I set button below image?

This is my css code:

```
.news_img{
  margin:0 20 0 20;
  float:left;
}
.trailer_button{
    z-index:999;
    float:left;
    margin:1 20 -20 20;
    width:181px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.buttonimg{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

`.news_img` is image
`.trailer_button` is button
`-buttonimg` is div around button and image

This is HTML

```
<div class="movie_box">
    <h3 class="h3">'.$movies['name'].'</h3>'
    <div class="buttonimg">
        <div class="news_img">
            <img src="'.$movies['cover'].'"/>
        </div>
        <button class="trailer_button" type="button">Trailer</button>
```

Comment: ummm, what???? It's unclear...

Comment: Please edit your post and add your HTML code.

Comment: i want to set this trailer button under img

Comment: there are serious problems with your css, missing `px` in many values

Comment: Umm. . . What? That isn't even a question.

Comment: Lol my work is blocking that link...I wonder if it's because it starts with "prn". Yeah, either create a fiddle, or include HTML

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to match the image you posted. Specifically, the code here is missing the text content (movie information) that appears in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the `<br/>` Mor Haviv suggested, or just remove the floats:

Here's a running [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c8103jz/)

```
.news_img{
  margin:0 20 0 20;

}
.trailer_button{
    z-index:999;

    margin:1 20 -20 20;
    width:181px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.buttonimg{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be your HTML code:

```
<div class="movie_box">
    <h3 class="h3">'.$movies['name'].'</h3>'
    <div class="buttonimg">
        <div class="news_img">
            <img src="'.$movies['cover'].'"/>
            <br/>
            <button class="trailer_button" type="button">Trailer</button>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inserting the button in to the image div, and using 
 to create a new line, just under the picture and put the button there.

jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/1a0mzqz0/

Comment: @IvanGorky I added jsFiddle. You can see it's working perfectly fine there.