# CSS How to add a button below an image

Tags: html, css, image, button

I have searched through the web, but couldn't find an answer.

I want to put buttons below several images which are in a table, like so:

```
__________  _________
|        | |        |
| image  | | image2 |
|________| |________|
|_button_| |_button2|
```

I tried using line breaks (like suggested here: [How can I set button below image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371917/how-can-i-set-button-below-image)), but it didn't work. The button(s) would be placed weirdly.

It would be nice to position them relatively to the images, as they should always be below them.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/1dw55eu7/1/

just wrap your image inside a div and your button inside another div, so the button will be cascaded directly below the image then you can style your button's div as you like for example make the button centered below the image as in the sample provided.

CSS

```
.imgButton{
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
  <div class="imgContainer">
            <div>
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRPy7ZnI46zizXRVoXLbV4Gl6LamFU6g5pqtJj1ijxnO8i-gJWp" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            </div>
            <div class="imgButton">
                <button value="test">test</button>
            </div>
     </div>
        </td>
  <td>
  <div class="imgContainer">
            <div>
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRPy7ZnI46zizXRVoXLbV4Gl6LamFU6g5pqtJj1ijxnO8i-gJWp" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            </div>
            <div class="imgButton">
                <button value="test">test</button>
            </div>
     </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this also works well. I think this is a better style for coding than putting the buttons into a figcaption.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add the button + make them same width of the image add to the JS fiddle Adel suggest

```
.imgContainer img, 
.imgContainer .imgButton button {
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1dw55eu7/3/
after update